# How to ask a user to answer to my question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about a game library and there's a guy named [Gama11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2631715/gama11) who has contributed to the library. He generally answers my question about the library. As I say I have a question but I don't know how to ask him to answer my question. Perhaps I just need to wait for a while until he find my question.

Answer (score 6):

This is not how Stack Exchange works, or is supposed to work. The system is set up to focus on the posts, not the users.

If the question can *only* be answered by the author of the library, then you should see the web page of the library; they probably have a forum, a mailing list or an area for bug reports and/or feature requests.

If the question is fit for Stack Exchange, then it shouldn't really matter who answers it.

Obviously the author of a library would likely be the most knowledgeable person and an answer from them would be ideal. But if someone else has the right answer to your question - then what really matters is that you got your answer, not who provided it.

Stack Exchange deliberately doesn't provide much in the way of directly contacting users. Some high-rep users would be drowned in personal requests.

Comment: Some lower-rep users already get enough *email* on *topics they know nothing about*. For example, me. And I don't even have my email directly on my profile.